# What is the proper way to annotate a function that returning file?

Tags: python-3.x, types, annotations

I'm annotating a function that returning html file. What's the proper type for the output? Right now I'm using 'object', but may be it is too broad.

```
@app.route('/')
def homepage() -> object:
"""
This function loads the homepage.

:return: the homepage index.html
"""
return send_from_directory(
    os.path.join(app.root_path, 'templates'),
    "index.html"
)
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: well whatever `send_from_directory` returns... do `print(type(end_from_directory(<w/e variables you send it>))` and see what type it is... is it a `file` object ? an `str` object?  a `bytes` object?

Comment: That's a smart suggestion! The type of the output is: <class 'flask.wrappers.Response'>

Comment: But the answer given is still too broad...

Comment: well that's the type of the object... if you want to document exactly the nature of this object that's what function documentation is for